# Как работает лицензионное соглашение в debian пакетах?

Tags: linux, debian, лицензирование, пакет

При установке программы на windows у меня выводится окошко с просьбой прочесть лицензионное соглашение и поставить галочку если вы согласны, но при установке программы на дистрибутиве linux семейства debian у меня ничего не выводится, просто ввожу команду `apt install имяпакета` и программа устанавливается на пк,лицензионное соглашение хранится в файле `/usr/share/doc/имякаталога/copyright`.

Насколько это правильно и имеет ли лицензионное соглашение установленное таким образом юридическую силу?

Comment: Хороший вопрос. Попробуйте решить его экспериментально... и опубликуйте результаты

Comment: @avp, обязательно, спасибо за совет

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### ответ про то, *почему* «там» так, а «тут» эдак.

как правило, проприетарное программное обеспечение распространяется вместе с [eula](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5) («end-user license agreement» — лицензионное соглашение с конечным пользователем»).

краткая суть eula — вы, как пользователь п.о., соглашаетесь с ограничениями **использования** п.о., выдвинутыми правообладателями. **распространение** же, как правило, вообще строго запрещается.

---

свободное же программное обеспечение распространяется вместе с лицензиями, **не** накладывающими никаких ограничений на **использование** п.о.

те или иные свободные лицензии выдвигают некоторые требования в отношении **распространения**. например, «можно распространять на тех же условиях, на которых вы сами получили» (gpl-подобные лицензии), или «можно распространять в любой форме, но с упоминанием авторов» (bsd-подобные лицензии), и т.п.

#### резюме:

если ограничиваются возможности использования (п.о. с *eula*), до начала использования требуется выразить согласие с этими ограничениями.

если использовать можно без каких-либо ограничений (свободное п.о.), то и «соглашаться» просто не с чем.

Comment: Получается я могу использовать лицензию freeware не получая пользовательское соглашение от пользователя?

Comment: 1. [freeware](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Бесплатное_программное_обеспечение) — это проприетарное п.о. не путайте со [свободным](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Свободное_программное_обеспечение). 2. своё п.о. вы можете распространять на любых условиях. 3. пользовательское соглашение (eula) получают пользователи от правообладателей, а не наоборот.

Comment: То есть я могу не накладывать ограничений на использование своего ПО, но могу запретить его распространение без eula? И считается ли декомпиляция ПО его использованием?

Comment: если у вас появился новый вопрос, задайте его, пожалуйста, с помощью кнопки «[задать вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)» в правом вернем углу страницы. если надо указать контекст, можете привести ссылку на данный вопрос

Answer (score 1):

Если вы таки откроете текстовичок с лицензией GPL, вы найдете там это:

> You are not required to accept this License in order to receive or run
> a copy of the Program. Ancillary propagation of a covered work
> occurring solely as a consequence of using peer-to-peer transmission
> to receive a copy likewise does not require acceptance. However,
> nothing other than this License grants you permission to propagate or
> modify any covered work. These actions infringe copyright if you do
> not accept this License. Therefore, by modifying or propagating a
> covered work, you indicate your acceptance of this License to do so.

Перевод ([отсюда](http://docs.evo.im/01_info/10_more/perevod_gnu_gplv3.html))

> Вы не обязаны принимать Данную Лицензию чтобы получить или запустить
> копию Программы. В дополнении, тиражирование лицензированного
> произведения, происходящее исключительно как совокупность передач от
> пользователя к пользователю, требуемых для получения копии также не
> требует соглашения. Однако, только Данная Лицензия даёт Вам права
> тиражирования или изменения любых лицензированных произведений. Такие
> действия нарушают авторское право, если Вы не приняли Данную Лицензию.
> Поэтому изменяя или тиражируя лицензированное произведение, Вы
> подтверждаете своё согласие с Данной Лицензией.

Comment: то есть, лицензия действует независимо от того принимал ее пользователь или нет?

Comment: Так как я не юрист, я не могу толковать для вас данную лицензию. Я привел оригинальный текст и более-менее похожий на правду перевод. Учтите, что юридическую значимость имеет только текст лицензии на английском языке.

Comment: @gpg, про английский не знал, спасибо

Comment: да и не везде есть хотя бы похожий текст, в лицензии apache такого нет

Comment: @НиколайНиколаевич не обязательно, что там будет точно такой же текст. Важно понимать, что авторы лицензий вольны выбирать, какие действия пользователя они считают согласием с лицензией, и не всегда это постановка галки. Иногда пишут, что *используя данный продукт, вы принимаете лицензионное соглашение*, например.

Comment: Хорошо, теперь понятнее